# How do I not duplicate a text in while loop?

Tags: php

```
// Show publications by research name 
$queryItem = "SELECT * FROM research_area, papers WHERE research_area.papers_id = papers.papers_id";
$resultItem = mysqli_query($link, $queryItem) or die(mysqli_error($link));



mysqli_close($link);
?>

// Motion Planning and the rest of the names kept repeating. I NEED only one time output to show all result.


            <?php 
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultItem)) { 

                ?>

                <?php
    if ($row['area_name'] == "Motion Planning") {
        echo "<h3>" . "Motion Planning" . "</h3>";
        echo "<b>" . $row['author'] . "</b>" . "<br>";
        echo "<b>" . $row['description'] . "</b>" . "<br>";
        echo "<a href = " . $row['pdf'] . ">PDF" . "</a>" . "<br>";

} elseif ($row['area_name'] == "Probabilistic Motion Planning") {
    echo "<h3>" . "Probabilistic Motion Planning" . "</h3>";
    echo "<b>" . $row['author'] . "</b>" . "<br>";
    echo "<b>" . $row['description'] . "</b>" . "<br>";
    echo "<a href = " . $row['pdf'] . ">PDF" . "</a>" . "<br>";

} elseif ($row['area_name'] == "Sampling Strategies for PRM Planning") {
    echo "<h3>" . "Sampling Strategies for PRM Planning" . "</h3>";
    echo "<b>" . $row['author'] . "</b>" . "<br>";
    echo "<b>" . $row['description'] . "</b>" . "<br>";
    echo "<a href = " . $row['pdf'] . ">PDF" . "</a>" . "<br>";
```

}
    ?>

```
       <?php } ?>
```

```
//////////// OUTPUT //////////////
Motion Planning
J. Basch, L.J. Guibas, D. Hsu, and A.T. Nguyen.
Disconnection proofs for motion planning.
PDF

Motion Planning
M. Erdmann, D. Hsu, M. Overmars, and F. van der Stappen, editors.
Algorithmic Foundations of Robotics VI
PDF

Motion Planning
H.H. Gonz�lez-Ba�os, D. Hsu, and J.C. Latombe.
Motion planning: Recent developments.
PDF
```

Probabilistic Motion Planning
D. Hsu, J.C. Latombe, R. Motwani, and L.E. Kavraki. 
Capturing the connectivity of high-dimensional geometric spaces by parallelizable random sampling techniques.
PDF

Probabilistic Motion Planning
D. Hsu.
Randomized Single-query Motion Planning in Expansive Spaces.
PDF

Probabilistic Motion Planning
D. Hsu, J.C. Latombe, and H. Kurniawati.
On the probabilistic foundations of probabilistic roadmap planning.
PDF

Sampling Strategies for PRM Planning
D. Hsu, L.E. Kavraki, J.C. Latombe, R. Motwani, and S. Sorkin.
On finding narrow passages with probabilistic roadmap planners. 
PDF

Sampling Strategies for PRM Planning
D. Hsu, T. Jiang, J. Reif, and Z. Sun.
The bridge test for sampling narrow passages with probabilistic roadmap planners.
PDF

Comment: can you provide a brief summary of what you are trying to achieve and what exactly is the issue with your code that you can't fix

Comment: I just need one "Motion Planning" text to show all the output. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to organize the result data of the query first, and then print it.**

So, let's start by defining a array abobve the while() clycle, then put your data into the array, organizaed by 'area_name' an then iterate over the array for print the info.

```
// Declare a new array for organize the data, $result in this case.
$result = array(); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultItem)) 
    { 

       // Here, instead of filter and print data, we are gonna organize it 
       // in a arrays inside the $result array

       // For example, for each record with 'area_name' in the query result,
       // we are gonna get a sub-array whit the data

       $result[$row['area_name']][] = array(
            'author' =>  $row['author'], 
            'description' => $row['description'], 
            'pdf' =>  $row['pdf'], 

            );
    }

// Now we can iterate over the $result array whit the foreach() function.    

foreach ($result as $key => $value) 
    {
        echo "<h3>" . $key . "</h3>";
        foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) 
            {
                echo "<b>" . $value2['author'] . "</b>" . "<br>";
                echo "<b>" . $value2['description'] . "</b>" . "<br>";
                echo "<a href = " . $value2['pdf'] . ">PDF" . "</a>" . "<br>";          
            }
    }
```

Try it, i'm gonna do a few tests, and if necesary edit this answer.

Comment: I have a TOTAL of 13 area_name. If I were to do a elseif statement, for instance, elseif ($row['area_name'] == "Geometric Computation".. Where will I put all the area_name instead of duplicating it? There seems to be an error if I put all the area_names outside the while loop :/

Comment: Course, i say that in case you only need the 'Motion planning' label. Edit your question, add the end of the code, where you close the 'if' and the 'while' statements and i can help ;)

Comment: I'm new to this. Just wanna learn simple coding. Hope my edited question is helpful :/

Comment: Is this still using php? Alright I will try my best! Thankyou :)

Comment: Yes, only php, can you edit your question and provide a model of the table  s that have the data? with these models i can test the code myself and gave you a tested and functional code as an answer

Comment: Papers table: papers_id(1), area_name(motion planning)


Research_area table:  research_area_id(1), papers_id(1), author(J. Basch, L.J. Guibas, D. Hsu, and A.T. Nguyen.), year_of_publication(2001), description(Disconnection proofs for motion planning.), research_place(In Proc. IEEE Int. Conf. on Robotics & Automation, pp. 1765-1772, 2001.), pdf(discon.pdf)
this is one of the data of the 2 tables i have

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are asking is for the heading "Motion Planning" to appear once before all "Motion Planning" papers, and then "Probabilistic Motion Planning" once before each "Probabilistic Motion Planning" paper, and then "Sampling Strategies for PRM Planning" once before each "Sampling Strategies for PRM Planning" paper. This is a common pattern when iterating over data that is in different categories.

Use a variable to track the `area_name` of the previous row, and put the code that echoes the header in an if statement that checks whether the current `area_name` is not equal to the previous row's `area_name`. You can set this variable to an empty string before your loop (as long as none of your data will include an empty `area_name` that you want to print a header for) and then set it to `$row['area_name']` as the last statement within the loop.

You will need to make sure the data is sorted by `area_name`, because the header is printed every time the current `area_name` differs from the previous. If they are not in order, this change could occur multiple times. Include an `ORDER BY` clause in your SQL to implement this.

Also, there is no need for there to be an if statement for each `area_name` if the value you are echoing is the same as the value from the row. Instead, `echo "<h3>" . $row['area_name'] . "</h3>";`